# Plausible Mechanisms for Polyketide Formation from Phloroglucinol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am working on modifying the reaction below. I am adding the sulfonate (ignore the sulfonic acid groups shown) groups so that polysubstitution of the phloroglucinol does not occur. In terms of the reactivity of the sulfonate, there should not be any issue, as it is not acidic and will not interfere with the potassium hydroxide in the first step of the original reaction; however, I am worried about how the electron withdrawing properties of the sulfonate will affect the overall reaction. The paper does not attempt to explain the reaction mechanism of this particular step, so I am not sure how exactly this form of substitution will affect my reaction. My only guess as of now is that the keto-enol tautomerization is a stabilizing factor of the final product, rendering substitution of the -OH groups unfavorable; however, this still does not predict how this reaction would be affected by sulfonate groups?

---

[image][image]

Edit: New possible mechanism for reaction
[image]

---

---

Comment: I have really never seen any reference to a reaction mechanism that involves the dearomatization of aryl moities like this (besides the Birch reduction, which is most likely not similar to this mechanism since it involves free radicals), so I'm not sure where to start with this analysis.

Comment: The most that I could find on this reaction was that it is known as a C-alkylation reaction

Comment: It's the same mechanism as electrophilic aromatic substitution, just without the deprotonation at the end, simply because there's no proton to remove.

Comment: Why would the reaction favor the formation of the polyketide in the original reaction and not the substituted phloroglucinol? The directing effect of the -OH groups would even seem to favor this. It could be that the polyketide is just very stable, even more than its aromatic counterparts, but I'm not very sure of this. Also, why is there no Lewis-acid catalyst if this follows a similar mechanism to electrophilic aromatic substitution?

Comment: (1) the question about regioselectivity is good. I am not entirely sure myself. (2) You probably know that EAS on electron-rich rings is easy. Phenol and aniline both react with bromine, without any need for Lewis acid catalysis. This ring is at least 3 times more activated than phenol.

Comment: I have added a new possible mechanism that is based on the electrophilic aromatic substitution reaction and a keto-enol tautomerization. This would explain the choice of reagents for the reaction, sodium hydroxide followed by HCl treatment and also the long reaction time; however, this mechanism would mean that my modified reaction would not work, as there will be no hydrogen that can be removed in keto-enol tautomerization. As for the regioselectivity of the reaction, my guess is that the product is probably thermodynamically favored, not kinetically favored given the reaction time.

Comment: I may be able to modify the procedure given in the link to have a shorter reaction time, this may favor the formation of the monosubstituted product without the need for sulfonation; however, it could also mean there will be a mixture of polyketide and substituted phloroglucinol.

Comment: In your new possible mechanism with the methylated phloroglucinol, you would need base to deprotonated the OH group(s) and then most likely you obtain O-methylation. Methyl bromide is not nucleophilic enough to react without deprotonation.

Comment: I have proposed a new mechanism that is consistent with the low-nucleophilicity of alkyl bromides. This may also explain the regioselectivity of reaction towards the polyketide, as the deprotonation of the -OH group allows for the direct formation of the product in a single concerted mechanism. The product would then undergo keto-enol tautomerization to yield the most stable tautomer. This would fully explain the choice of reagents by the authors of the paper. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: If this mechanism is most consistent, that would mean that my original proposal of sulfonation as a type of blocking group would theoretically work, although I am concerned about a nucleophilic attack at the C-sulfonate bond instead of the C-alkyl bond, which would ruin the point of the sulfonation in the first place.

Comment: This paper involves C-alkylation of phloroglucinol with allylic and benzylic halides: https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0040402004008853?token=71D3FBC2A32DF5CDCBB98D6EBB9DEAB36539FFD37E73202A1D0B867D81B95F214BC6E8365ACB1DBCE5CCF1054115060B